# for-loop in django

Tags: python, django

How can I do for-loop like this in Django?

```
list = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']
```

==========================================

```
{% for x in len(list), for y in list %}

<p>{{x}}: {{y}}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Answer (score 3):

The best option is the `enumerate` function.

```
return render_template("index.html", list=enumerate(list))
```

Then in the template:

```
{% for index, value in list %}

    <p>{{index}}: {{value}}</p>

{% endfor %}
```